# How to theme date combo input side-by-side?

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

I'd like to theme a date combo field on a node edit form to be side by side, rather than stacked vertically, as shown below. Dates are popups, if that makes a difference.

I'm working with the admin theme Seven, which I've sub-themed, in order to override theme functions or CSS as needed. What is the approach should I take for this kind of customization? Moving the "to" label isn't strictly necessary, but would be nice if possible.

Before
[image: date combo before]

After
[image: date combo after]

Also wondering if there is some good reason why the to and from fields are arranged this way?

Edit: instructions for creating a subtheme are here: https://drupal.org/node/225125 This is an easy way to customize an Admin theme if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the CSS provided by the module, the boxes are foreseen as block elements. Even the used classes on the form fields are `date-no-float`, so for some reason they don't want that the fields are shown in column layout ...

The fact that you used a sub theme for your admin, you can add these CSS styles (based on `Seven` theme) in your css file. These will create the desired result you want.

```
.date-no-float { float: left; width: auto; clear: none; }
.date-no-float > .form-item > label { float: left; margin: 34px 40px 0 30px; }
.start-date-wrapper { clear: left; }
```

Comment: @ Mike Vranckx - Excellent. This worked straightaway, and the result looks just like the After screen above.

Answer (score 0):

You could also theme the output of the widget with this template override

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date.theme/function/theme_date_combo/7